# Java Spring security does not appear to recognize disabled LDAP accounts

Tags: java, spring-security, openldap, spring-ldap

**See Edit-1 below for sum-up question**

I am using Spring Security libraries (v3.0.5) to handle authentication for a web application (deployed in JBoss AS7). The account management is handled by an IdM on top of OpenLDAP.

When a new account is created, by default it is created with the "*nsaccountlock*" operational attribute set to "true". We can confirm that the account is "Disabled" by logging into the IdM web portal and listing the users - new users are listed as Disabled.

The problem is that our web application seems to ignore that *nsaccountlock* attribute completely when it searches for a user entry. The springframework logs report "Enabled: true" for all accounts that attempt to authenticate, whether they have the *nsaccountlock=true* or *false*.

I have searched through as much of the springframework source code as I can find, and I can not find anything that is actually setting the "enabled" state to false (see *org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl* and any subclass). I would have expected it to happen in *org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsMapper.mapUserFromContext()* but it definitely does not set the Enabled flag anywhere.

The LDAP lookup and entry retrieval is configured in several .xml files (which I am unfortunately unable to post here at the moment) that define the use of classes such as *org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider, org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch*, etc.

Should I be using a different type of *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails* implementation to capture the disabled state from LDAP? Am I missing some obvious configuration element that would indicate how Spring can determine the disabled state of the LDAP entry?

Note: I can configure the LDAP search to fetch the "nsaccountlock" as an attribute in the UserDetails response, and the attribute is logged correctly 
(whether the value is true or false) but it still does not affect the "enabled" boolean value. It just acts as another bit of metadata (like phone, address, email, etc).

**Edit-1**

I may have been asking the wrong question up front. Ultimately, I would like to know this:

**What would lead LdapUserDetailsImpl.isEnabled() to return false? i.e., What do we need to do in order to make sure Spring Security recognizes disabled accounts?**

I'm hoping this a matter of configuration. I imagine it has something to do with the AuthenticationManager (we use org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticatoinManagerImpl)

Thanks for the help, and I apologize for the messy question.

Comment: Do you use bind authentication? The bind should fail if account is locked.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of authentication is being used. I can say that we are configured to use org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl as the authentication manager. It is configured with some Principal Resolvers (like com.jericho.cas.authentication.principal.CustomUsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver).
The LDAP search is handled by org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch which internally invokes org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(). Regardless, there are no bind failures...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know OpenLDAP and the LDAP protocol, `nsaccountlock` is not an attribute which is used by OpenLDAP to keep track of locked account, it is an attribute which was used in Sun Directory Server (Sun LDAP Directory).

But from the point of view of OpenLDAP it is the same as any other informative attribute.

If you want to manage a password policy you have to implement the overlay `ppolicy` which is described [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html)